# Android draw with finger over webView doesn't scroll the webview while drawing

Tags: android

With reference to this link [Android draw with finger over webView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951329/answer/submit)

i am able to draw anything on HTML page but not able to scroll the page as on ontouch it is drawing.. please help me to solve the issue so as to be able to draw on a html page and to scroll the Webview content as well..

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The given solution in mentioned link is different in that custom view is on top of `webview` and takes full screen so `touch` will be handled by `customView` not `webView`.

You can do 2 things

1. extend webView and implement finger drawing feature there.
2. implement `DispatchTouchEvent(Motion)` and pass touch to your webView based on some condition.