# How can I draw an rectangle in a android webview?

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to load an external web page (it can be any website) in my android app within an webview. I then want to draw a rectangle around a specific text or an image.

I have the css coordinates where I want to draw the rectangle and of its size. I don't want to change the css layout of the page, only overlay the page with this rectangle.

Then I want to automatically zoom in on the page to the area marked with the rectangle.

Is this possible?

If yes, how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9951979/3780625

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android draw with finger over webView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951329/android-draw-with-finger-over-webview)